# How to remove OEM branding on PC startup?

Tags: windows-10

Sorry if this has been asked before, but I didn't find anything when searching.

I bought a prebuilt computer from newegg a while back. It was apparently manufactured by Avatar, because when I start the PC up, it promptly displays the AVATAR logo before running bios and login screen. Is there any way to remove this splash screen?

One video I watched said to go to regedit > Local_Machine > Software > Microsoft > Windows > CurrentVersion > OEMInformation and delete the whole folder. I did that but the splash screen still appears.

Comment: If at all, you can disable it in the BIOS.

Comment: And I don't know how to do that, and thats why I'm asking, and thats why I'm getting downvoted? Friendly community

Comment: No you probably got downvoted for not doing any research yourself. Did you google "remove bios splash screen" or "remove manufacturer splash screen"?

Comment: Like I said, I searched but didn't know to search for keyword bios. There were no results when searching this site for remove OEM splash. What is this site for then?

Comment: @wizloc Like [Manny g](http://superuser.com/a/1014523/270195) said you could only do that if you have access to firmware source or your motherboard manufacturer has tools that allow you to do that. Like this one from [asus](http://www.asus.com/in/support/FAQ/1003347/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure that this is in the BIOS, not the OS or the hard drive, and can only be disabled from within the BIOS, if at all.

Closest thing is to turn on quickboot, which will skip the self check and probably skip the splash screen.

Comment: Setting any fast boot options never removed any logo displays on any of the many machines I ever had. It just skips floppy searches and similar time consuming stuff.

Comment: It does on my Toshiba, and also did on my HP Mini. At least if I remember correctly. Maybe it was just so quick I didn't notice

Comment: Thanks. I found it in BIOS under Advanced Settings and it was called Full Screen LOGO Show. Just had to disable that

Answer (score 3):

I don't think you can override the logo since it is most likely embedded in the cmos firmware. You will need to have the source code for that motherboard firmware and edit it. In other words, don't think there is a way. Windows has nothing to do with what is being displayed before windows loads. Sorry.